# MySQL ADD CONSTRAINT fail with [Err] 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I created two tables with the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `dinnertable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tableName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tableStatus` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `orderDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `food` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foodName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foodType_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mprice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But I can not ALTER the food TABLE to ADD CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE food ADD CONSTRAINT fk_food_foodType_id FOREIGN KEY(foodType_id) REFERENCES foodType(id);
```

With the error info:

> [SQL] ALTER TABLE food ADD CONSTRAINT fk_food_foodType_id FOREIGN KEY(foodType_id) REFERENCES foodType(id);
>   [Err] 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: just curious, did you create your database with the default engine=innoDB; for all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the `foodType` table in your foreign key constraint definition. You should create that table *before* adding a constraint to it.

Moreover, that table should have field `id` as a primary key, matching the type of `foodType_id`.

Comment: 3 minutes later.;)